# Удалить пробелы между числами при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Необходимо удалить все пробелы между числами, используя при этом регулярные выражения. 
То есть из строки `"Просто строка с числами 2    000 123 2   4"` нужно получить -
`"Просто строка с числами 200012324"`.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String regex="(?<=\\d+)\\s+(?=\\d+)";
    String source="Просто строка с числами 2 000     123 2 4";
    System.out.println(source.replaceAll(regex,""));
    }
}
```